# Как организовать подсвечивание 3D объекта с которым происходит контакт?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Хочу повторить некий "Select(); - Deselect();", как показано на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите советом, как это реализовать или что нужно прочитать для реализации данной фичи.

P.S. Скриншот из игры "Overcooked"

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что нужно в итоге получить. Смею предположить, что нужна обводка объекта, а это шейдеры.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker когда игрок подходит к объекту с котором он будет взаимодействовать, то он "подсвечивается". Обводка немного не то слово. Да, возможно шейдеры. Может есть какие-то махинации наподобие RGBA для материала с альфа-каналом? Или я не в ту степь иду?

Comment: соорудил шейдер для обводки, примерно как в инспекторе желтым, если нтересно - пишите оформлю ответ https://i.imgur.com/Q3tGCQo.png

Comment: не старался с качеством обводки, рисуется она пост-эффектом при помощи шейдера, и рендера в текстуру...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7usBawh.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ опять же. Тут необходимо скорее подсвечивание объекта в целом, а не лишь контур, да так чтобы основной объект был виден. Завтра по возможности дополню вопрос, чтобы не было неясностей.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer тоже не проблема, добавить яркость или изменить цвет

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2sxVXek

Answer (score -1):

В даном случае скорее всего выделяемые обьекты имеют материал/шейдер с поддержкой яркости материала или же цветом.

Например, если зайти в `Legacy Shader/Bumped Diffuse`
там окроме бампа и нормалмапа будет `Main Color` которым можно изменить цвет текстурки.